# How to subtract a decimal time from a clock time in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have the following PHP script:

```
<?php
  $clockTime = "10:00 AM";
  $decimalTime = "0.75"; // represents time in hours in decimal format

  echo date( 'g:i A', strtotime( strtotime( $clockTime ) . ' -'.$decimalTime.' hours' ) ); // returns "7:00 PM" when I need it to return "9:15 AM"
?>
```

How can I get the script to properly calculate and return **9:15 AM** rather than **7:00 PM**?

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` returns the time in seconds, so you need to convert the decimal time in seconds:

```
<?php
date( 'g:i A', strtotime( $clockTime ) - $decimalTime * 60 * 60 ) ); 
?>
```

However, this will not work when daylight saving (DST) comes into play. Especially if your code will be run in different countries, use timezones and the `DateTime`-API:

```
<?php
$date = new \DateTime($clockTime); // This uses the system default timezone where the server is located
$date->sub(new \DateInterval('PT' . ((int) $decimalTime * 60 * 60) . 'S'));
echo $date->fomat('g:i A');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @giraff. I'll work on this. BTW, what is the significance of the `'PT'`? Does that represent pacific time? If so I am located in Eastern Time Zone and my server is located in Central Time Zone. Does that matter?